# MASM x86 How to print multi-lined string variable?

Tags: string, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm having some trouble printing a multi lined string to the console window. Once the program is ran to display a menu, only the first line of the string prints to the console window.

How can I create a string variable that displays on multiple lines?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
.data
    prompt BYTE "Please choose and option below.",0
    menu BYTE "Option 1",0     
    BYTE "Option 2",0     
    BYTE "Option 3",0     
    BYTE "Exit", 0

.code
main proc 
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WRITESTRING
    call CRLF
    mov edx, OFFSET menu
    call WRITESTRING
    call CRLF
    invoke ExitProcess,0
    main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 0):

`WRITESTRING` prints a 0-terminated string.  You've included a `0` byte after `"Option 1"`, so it stops there.

**Separate lines in the asm source aren't what matters**.  What you wrote assembles the same bytes into your object file as

```
; assembles the same as what you did
menu BYTE "Option 1",0, "Option 2",0, "Option 3",0
```

---

Instead, you need is to **include a newline in your string**.  For DOS, this is a 2-byte sequence of CR LF  (ASCII codes `10` and `13`).

```
menu BYTE "Option 1", 10, 13, "Option 2", 10, 13
     BYTE "Option 3", 10, 13, 0

; break this up into multiple lines in the source however you want
; I made this intentionally inconsistent to make a point
```

(Including the CR LF at the end of the string means you don't have to separately `call CRLF`).

Comment: I didnt know that I could just type everything up on one line so long as I used 0 to terminate the string. Thank you for the information. I assumed there was a way to do it but could not find any information as to how.